# Update data in list dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, auto-update

First post here on stack overflow.

I'm creating a YouTube stream monitor to keep an eye on multiple streams simultaneously and all was going well until i tried to work out how to update the data. Ive connected to the API, got the data into a json format and got the page working well. The problem now comes with updating the data and whilst i could just refresh the data section every x seconds that would cause the embedded video to refresh every time.

```
<?php
$url = "data_template.json"; //static json for development
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);

$html = null;

foreach ($data->data as $program) {
    $html .= "<li id='1'>
              <img src='images/test.jpg' width='100%'>
              <!--YouTube Stream <iframe> embed -->
              <button>Public</button><button disabled>Preview - Not Enabled</button>
              <h4> {$program->broadcast->title} ( {$program->broadcast->id} )</h4>
              <p id='broad'>Broadcast Status: {$program->broadcast->lifeCycleStatus} </p>
              <p>Stream Status:  {$program->stream->streamStatus}  and  {$program->stream->healthStatus} </p>
              <p>Last Updated:  {$program->stream->lastUpdate} </p>
              </li>";
        };

echo $html;

?>
```

I would like to update the variables within the paragraphs of each list but am struggling to work out how to get to them. Ive tried the below but it doesn't seem very efficient.

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("1");
    x.querySelector("#broad").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
</script>
```

Would i be better adding an intermediate step and having different variables in the HTML that can be individually ID'd and updated?

Comment: If you want to use `getElementById()` the HTML tags have to have an id i.e. `<p id="xxx">` Please start by reading a few BASIC javascript tutorials. There are 1000's out there waiting for you

Comment: Yeah i worked that bit out. Sorry its not in the example. The issue there is with `<p>Stream Status:  {$program->stream->streamStatus}  and  {$program->stream->healthStatus} </p>`. How might you select each bit?

Comment: If you want to use `querySelector("#broad")` then there has to be some tag that has a `class="broad"` Again **hit the books and tutorials** SO is not a learning resource

Comment: @RiggsFolly as I said above i haven'I included it in the example. I cleaned all of my playing with different ideas out to show the original code. I understand you would have to give things IDs

Comment: If code does not match HTML then how are we supposed to be of assistance in any way other than to say that is not gona work

Comment: I have updated the question with the IDs. It still doesn't get over the fact I think its un-efficient and the wrong way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, I would change your `<li>` tags to `<div>` tags, its more presentable and more concise with W3C standards.
- Next you need to come up with the JS that would get the element you desire. You should highly consider jQuery. Its way easier to handle for a beginner like yourself.
- Finally, when creating your HTML add a class to each element you will need to update with JS later.

So for example if your HTML is like this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script><!-- jQuery lib -->

<div class="video_block">
    <img src='images/test.jpg' width='100%'>
    <button>Public</button>
    <button disabled>Preview - Not Enabled</button>
    <h4><span class="title_1">Something</span> ( <span class="title_2">Something</span> )</h4>
    <p>Broadcast Status: <span class="b_status">Something</span> </p>
    <p>Stream Status:  <span class="s_status_1">Something</span>  and  <span class="s_status_2">Something</span> </p>
    <p>Last Updated:  <span class="u_status">Something</span> </p>
</div>
<div class="video_block">
    <img src='images/test.jpg' width='100%'>
    <button>Public</button>
    <button disabled>Preview - Not Enabled</button>
    <h4><span class="title_1">Something</span> ( <span class="title_2">Something</span> )</h4>
    <p>Broadcast Status: <span class="b_status">Something</span> </p>
    <p>Stream Status:  <span class="s_status_1">Something</span>  and  <span class="s_status_2">Something</span> </p>
    <p>Last Updated:  <span class="u_status">Something</span> </p>
</div>
```

Then your jQuery can be:

```
<script>
   $('.video_block').each(function(){
       $(this).find('.title_1').text("something else");
       $(this).find('.s_status_1').text("something else");
       $(this).find('.u_status').text("something else");
   });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how does the script know which `video_block` to work on?

Comment: Since you didnt mention that in your original question, I did not answer that way. Do you want to specify a specific block? If so, add IDs to each block, then you can call it by ID.

Comment: I (possibly wrongly) assumed that as there was a for loop in my original code along with saying i was monitoring multiple streams it might have been apparent.

Comment: Whilst ive not used your code exactly it has helped a lot. Thanks!!